# Why is HasRequired not working?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I'm trying to set a one-to-one relationship between a `User` table and a `UserSettings` table.

Despite specifying the 'HasRequired' relation, I'm still able to insert a user without any settings. Where am I going wrong?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        // Settings = new UserSettings();
    }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual UserSettings Settings { get; set; }
}

public class UserSettings
{
    [Key]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(t => t.Settings).WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.User);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you implement the `OnModelCreating()` method?

Comment: When you say "able to insert", what do you mean exactly? What is your code, what happens, and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Are you overriding `OnModelCreating()` in your app's derived DbContext? If not, you should do it there.

Comment: @LeonelMachava I'm overriding OnModelCreating()in my application DB context. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

See the relationship.
Here's the full working code :

```
    public class ApplicationUser 
        {
            public ApplicationUser()
            {
                // Settings = new UserSettings();
            }
                [Key]
            public string Id { get; set; }  //could be from the base class
            public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

            public virtual UserSettings Settings { get; set; }
        }

        public class UserSettings
        {
            [Key]
            public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

            public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        }

     public class Context : DbContext
            { 
              protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
                {
                    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                    modelBuilder.Entity<UserSettings>()
                                     .HasRequired(t => t.ApplicationUser)
                                     .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Settings);

                }
        }
```

I hope this helps...ApplicationUser has a foreign key .. in this case and is one to one map with UserSetting .

Comment: He has a base class `IdentityUser` that most likely contains the key. Otherwise he would get an exception before he even could try to insert an entity. Are you claiming with "*full working code*" that in your model inserting a user without settings is impossible?

Comment: @Slauma He hasn't mentioned his base class IdentityUser if it contains a key or not. But if has key inside, it will work for sure..

Comment: @Slauma I think he has the problem with relationship.. now I have changed the relationship, now without user settings, its not possible to enter application user ;)

Comment: @MkMoganty Slauma is correct, IdentityUser is a EntityFramework class which already has an id. column: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: @Jonathan Please check the fluent key mapping direction.. is that u need .. that without settings its not possible to enter users.  Regarding Identityuser i agreed with u and slauma.